# How can one use Eclipse for Java7 and Java6 interchangeably?

Tags: eclipse, java-7

Since, the "Java7 Solr/Lucene" bug in Java 7 seems to be resolved in update3 I want now to develop in Java7 but as most of the rest of the world uses Java6 I need to switch between Java7 and Java6 for different projects. How can I configure projects individually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that it's part of the project properties.

Google "eclipse build path" and one of the first few hits should take you to the eclipse help site and you'll get all the details you need.

Or try:
http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm